# Why is the prototype of the function 'Function' again a function and not an object like the prototype of the function 'Object'?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, prototypal-inheritance

`Function` and `Object` are special types of a function, since having a capital letter starting, they are constructor-functions, right?

Functions as 1st class citizens in JavaScript can have methods (functions that are stored as properties in an object), as well.

So functions are objects, right? The constructor-function `Function`'s property `prototype` has typeof "function" whereas the constructor-function `Object`'s property `prototype` has typeof "object".

Why isn't it "object" both times?

```
typeof Function.prototype
>"function"

typeof Object.prototype
>"object"

Function.prototype
> ƒ () { [native code] }

Object.prototype
> {…}
```

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: Interesting. I never realised that ;) Please note that these are not special functions other than being native functions. The capital-letter-constructor thing is just convention. Some can be used as constructor only, other can be used to coerce into a different type (e.g. `Number("42") //=> 42`). Other are just "namespace", e.g. you can't invoke `Math`)

Comment: Do I have to delete that question, since it is duplicate? Or is that done automatically?